# Split list into ascending sublists

Tags: list-manipulation, sequence

I would like to split a list into non-overlapping, ascending (more precisely, non-descending with ≤) sublists. The function would be close to [`LongestOrderedSequence`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LongestOrderedSequence.html), but instead of the longest one, we want *all* the ordered sequences. An example:

```mathematica
ls = {2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 1};

split[ls] == {{2, 3}, {1, 2, 3, 3}, {2}, {1}}
```

Comment: @user1066 Perfect — that should be an answer! Why did I presume that sequence-related functions should start with `Sequence` :)

Comment: @user1066 I suppose you mean [the first example or two](https://wolfram.com/xid/0gipg0-e65cv) under Generalizations & Extensions

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think this must be a duplicate, but as the answer below is (almost) identical to an example in [`Split`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Split.html), I have tagged it `Community Wiki` and posted what was originally a comment as an answer.

```
ls = {2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 1};

Split[ls, LessEqual]

(* {{2, 3}, {1, 2, 3, 3}, {2}, {1}} *)
```

Comment: That this is not in the lead makes me think active site users no longer have the ability to discern quality.

Answer (score 11):

Using `SequenceSplit`:

```
SequenceSplit[ls, {x_, y___}?OrderedQ :> {x, y}]

(*{{2, 3}, {1, 2, 3, 3}, {2}, {1}}*)
```

Answer (score 8):

Found a solution by myself:

```
SequenceCases[ls, {__}?OrderedQ]
```

Wonder if there's a neater one :)